# Настройка Webhook aiogram + nginx

Tags: python, nginx, aiogram, webhook

Установил nginx + letsencrypt
Добавил в файл nginx.config:

```
server {
                listen 80;
                listen 443 ssl;
                server_name vm.example;

                ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vm.example/fullchain.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vm.example/privkey.pem;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7771;
                        proxy_redirect     off;
                        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                }
        }
```

Пытаюсь запустить python-скрипт:

```
import aiogram

BOT_TOKEN = "Тут был токен"
# webhook settings
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://vm.example'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/'
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
WEBAPP_PORT = 7771

bot = aiogram.Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = aiogram.Dispatcher(bot=bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: aiogram.types.Message):
    await message.answer(text="Hello!")


async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    await bot.delete_webhook()


if name == 'main':
    aiogram.executor.start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        skip_updates=True,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

Скрипт запускается, но бот не видит сообщений. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: при выводе get_webhook_info()
{"url": "", "has_custom_certificate": false, "pending_update_count": 1}

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить http на  https в proxy_pass:

```
            location / {
                    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:7771;
                    ...
            }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -2):

Необходимо либо через executed стартануть с webhook или polling
Либо dp.start_polling